# Algorithm in SQL / C# to get an exact number of rows depending on variable?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sum

I need to get an automatic method to link certain number consumptions with a payment.

I have for example in my first table.

```
Payments 
ID      Amount 
1       $5,000
```

Then I have the following Table:

```
Consumptions
ID  Amount  CreatedDate
1   1000    2015-07-01 13:59
2   1000    2015-07-01 19:15
3   1000    2015-07-02 01:01
4   1500    2015-07-02 08:44
5   1000    2015-07-03 05:00
6   800     2015-07-03 19:57
7   200     2015-07-03 21:32
8   500     2015-07-03 23:48
```

I want to have a way that considering the $5000 payment amount, it automatically chooses the best combination of consumptions that make up the $5,000 sum.

If SQL is difficult, it can also be done on C#.

Comment: `SQL` is not geared up for this sort of thing, so it will have to be `C#`.  But what I don't understand, is how this is supposed to work if your `Consumptions` table has records with duplicate `amount` values?

Comment: You would use Stack Overflow to post your attempt at the Algorithm and it not working as expecting, Stack Overflow is not for having someone write your code for you

Comment: This is the Knapsack Problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Googles for "solving knapsack problem in SQL":  http://aprogrammerwrites.eu/?p=635#.VZcxenpVhBc

Answer (score 0):

You will need a CTE that recursively joins with itself and checks all possible combinations.

```
with Anchor 
(
   Select Id, Amount, 0 as Level
   From Consumptions
),
with RecursiveJoin
(

    Select Id, Amount, Level From Anchor
    Where Level = 0

    UNION ALL
    -- generate all possible permutations of amounts
    Select c2.Id, c1.Amount + c2.Amount, Level + 1
    From RecursiveJoin c1
    Left Join RecursiveJoin c2 on c1.Id < c2.Id -- eliminate self joins and palindromes

)
Select * 
From RecursiveJoin c
Join Payments p on c.Amount = p.Amount
```

I'm not completely confident that my recursion is correct.  Hopefully that gets you started on the concept.

I'll leave it to you to add fields that concatenate lists of Id's of consumptions in each recursion.

It will give you multiple matches since multiple combinations of consumptions could match a payment.  You could find the one with fewest combinations by keeping count in the recursion.